# how to write an IN predicate as a NOT IN predicate

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have the following query --

```
select ssn, fname, lname 
from employee, department
where (dname, dno) in (select dname, dno
                       from department, employee 
                       where dno=dnumber 
                       and dname <> 'Headquarters' 
                       and dname <> 'Administration');
```

`

It returns the `ssn`, `fname` and `lname` of employees who do not work in the headquarters or administration department.

I am having trouble reversing the logic and figuring out how to get the same result using "not in". From what I have gathered the "in" predicate goes through the tables and checks to see if it can create tuples of `fname`, `lname` and `ssn` which is based on the department number from the employee table matching the department number in the department table.

Comment: I don't understand... Why don't you just use "not in"? What is the expected result? You could also do a join by the way and get a much simpler query...

Comment: then make it `not in`, **OR** change to `dname = `?

Comment: and there is NO point in using a subselect for this, especially since the subselect is on the exact same tables. why can't you just have `select * from employee where dname not in ('hq', 'admin')`?

Comment: Independent of the `IN` issue, there's a problem with your query. You're joining the `employee` and `department` tables, but not specifying any joining condition.

Answer (score 1):

You have to invert the test in the subquery's `WHERE` clause using [de Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
select ssn, fname, lname 
from employee, department
where (dname, dno) not in (
    select dname, dno
    from department, employee 
    where dno != dnumber or dname IN ('Headquarters', 'Administration'));
```

Comment: Ah of course, thank you. For some reason Oracle does not like the use of IN within the nested select. However it does work like this:  where dno <> dnumber or dname = 'Headqaurters' or dname = 'Administration');

Do you know why that is?

Comment: My answer is for MySQL, I don't know Oracle. You should probably say something in the question to emphasize that you need solutions for both -- I didn't notice you had both tags.

Comment: The above query has one too many open parenthesis `(` in the sub select or one too few close parenthesis `)` so if you copied it verbatim that might be the source of the failure of the in operator.  Add one more closing paren at the end and it may well work.

Answer (score 0):

I find that aliasing helps me keep track of things:

```
SELECT emp.ssn, emp.fname, emp.lname
FROM employee emp, department dep1
WHERE emp.dnumber = dep1.dno   /* link the tables here */ 
AND (dep1.dno NOT IN (         /* subquery filters eligible results */
   SELECT dep2.dno
   FROM department dep2
   WHERE dep2.dname <> 'Headquarters'
   AND dep2.dname <> 'Administration') 
);
```

Note: I didn't test this, but it should be close.